# Saving Marketing Automation campaign throws an error

Tags: marketing-automation

When I create a new campaign in marketing automation from blank and save it, Sitecore throws an error:

```
ERROR [Sitecore Services]: HTTP POST
URL https://sitecoreclean93sc.dev.local/sitecore/api/ma/plans/?cultureName=en
Exception System.ArgumentNullException: activityType should not be null.
Parameter name: activityType
   at Sitecore.Framework.Conditions.RequiresValidator`1.ThrowExceptionCore(String condition, String additionalMessage, ConstraintViolationType type)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Conditions.Throw.ValueShouldNotBeNull[T](ConditionValidator`1 validator, String conditionDescription)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Conditions.ValidatorExtensions.IsNotNull[T](ConditionValidator`1 validator)
   at Sitecore.Marketing.Automation.Extensions.AutomationActivityDefinitionViewModelExtensions.ToDomainModel(AutomationActivityDefinitionViewModel viewModel, IActivityDescriptor activityType, CultureInfo culture, IActivityConverterFactory`1 activityConverterFactory, BaseLog logger, Boolean validate)
   at Sitecore.Marketing.Automation.Extensions.AutomationPlanDefinitionViewModelExtensions.ToDomainModel(AutomationPlanDefinitionViewModel viewModel, IActivityDescriptorLocator activityDescriptorLocator, CultureInfo culture, IActivityConverterFactory`1 activityConverterFactory, BaseLog logger, Boolean activate, DateTime createdAt, DateTime lastModifiedDate, IAutomationPlanDefinition existingPlan)
   at Sitecore.Marketing.Automation.Data.AutomationPlanRepository.<Add>d__11.MoveNext()
```

Same error occurs if I use marketing automation campaign from template, edit it and save it. I have deployed marketing definitions and rebuilt indexes. What should I try to do next?

I have Sitecore 9.3 installed locally through Graphical Installer.

Comment: Just to confirm you're creating a new marketing automation and without adding anything to it you're seeing this error when saving?

Comment: Yes. I even did a new clean installation of sitecore 9.3 again with graphical installer to make sure I havent broke something myself. Error occurs there too. So this error should be reproducable for everyone else.

Comment: Any Update on this? Same Problem here

Comment: No unfortunately, even Sitecore couldnt reproduce this problem. So far what I understood is that javascript doesnt always send backend all data what it should.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue, but in my case, the issue was when the automation campaign was getting saved, the language resolver was setting it to "en", but while retrieveing the default language was getting set to "en-us".

i would suggest checking your language resolver.

you can also check the language that is getting set in developer tools-> application tab.

search for "lang", you will see all the lang values getting set.

thanks,